# System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Eu muito provavelmente não estou conseguindo conectar a minha aplicação com o meu banco de dados com o Entity Framework Core, pois fica aparecendo este erro cujo eu não consigo decifrar.

Eu já pesquisei na documentação e já tentei fazer diversas coisas.

Além disso, eu também não consigo trabalhar com Entity Framework mapeando o meu modelo, pois aparece uma mensagem dizendo que está faltando as credenciais de usuário e de servidor.

Código Fonte:

```
public AgendaContext() : base()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring (DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=trabalho;user=root;password=123456789");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Agenda>()
                   .ToTable("tb_agenda");

            builder.Entity<Agenda>()
                   .HasKey(p => p.AgendaID);

            builder.Entity<Agenda>()
                   .Property(p => p.Nome)
                   .HasColumnType("varchar(80)");

            builder.Entity<Agenda>()
                   .Property(p => p.Endereco)
                   .HasColumnType("varchar(255)");

            builder.Entity<Agenda>()
                   .Property(p => p.DiaCompromisso)
                   .HasColumnType("date");

            builder.Entity<Agenda>()
                   .Property(p => p.HoraCompromisso)
                   .HasColumnType("time");

            builder.Entity<Agenda>()
                   .Property(p => p.Final)
                   .HasColumnType("time");
        }

        public DbSet<Agenda> Agenda { get; set; }
```

Erro:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Método get_Info no tipo
>   MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.MySQLOptionsExtension
>   do assembly MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.18.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d não tem uma
>   implementação.'

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a discussão citada pelo Felipe: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17788 é de fato um BUG, no caso ainda não saiu a correção oficial, no entanto é sugerido instalar o pacote.

Com PM:

```
Install-Package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
```

Com dotnet:

```
dotnet add package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
```

Depois de instalado a configuração segue assim https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#3-services-configuration:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;

namespace FooBar
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Troque SeuContexto pela classe do seu DbContext
            services.AddDbContextPool<SeuContexto>(options => options
                // ajuste os dados de conexão
                .UseMySql("Server=localhost;Database=ef;User=root;Password=1234;", mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions
                    // Ajuste a versão do seu servidor
                    .ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 18), ServerType.MySql))
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, porém, o código que foi postado, eu coloco aonde?

Comment: @GustavoOliveira mas você já não possui o código Startup no seu projeto?

Comment: Startup não, porém eu coloquei os códigos direto no DBContext, pois eu não conheço muito. Além disso, Eu tentei colocar no ponto inicial do meu programa e não deu certo....

Comment: Porque eu estou usando o Entity Framework Core no .Net Framework, ou seja, estou utilizando um aplicativo Windows Forms, por isso eu não estou conseguindo fazer a conexão...